# Why can't I see a suggested edit when I try to improve it?

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, improve-edit

I went to review a suggested edit (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4010680). The edit seemed reasonable, but could be better, so I clicked the 'Improve' button. This took me to an edit page, but the edit page only contained the original text of article - it did not show me the edit I wanted to improve. Looking at other 'improve' questions here on meta, this appears atypical - most people do see the edit on the improve page.

[Oded notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220096/why-cant-i-see-a-suggested-edit-when-i-try-to-improve-it#comment713089_220096) that what probably happened was that the edit was rejected after loading the suggested edit page but before clicking the ‘Improve’ button.

Comment: The suggested edit got rejected. It probably got rejected between the time you saw it and clicked the improve button, so you got the version **before** the suggested edit was made.

Comment: Any reason you thought it was good enough to improve?  In general the majority of the community does not agree with editing to add content to posts, so based on that idea, the edit rejection was proper.

Comment: @Oded - that makes sense. I wish the site would be a little more proactive about telling me not to bother reviewing the change - as you can see from my question, the current workflow is confusing.

Comment: @psubsee2003 The edit added useful content that I would have liked to see if I had posted the question, or found it via search. The English wasn't great, but the content was useful.

Comment: @Oded Getting the old version instead of the suggested edit doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Bruce so new answer was due, or maybe a comment on the existing answer. Not radically  changing it.

Comment: @Gilles: Why would you start with an edit that's already been rejected by the community?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because I disagree with the rejection? Because I was going to uncheck the “was helpful” checkbox? And anyway the UI should clearly indicate that it's showing the original instead of the suggested modification. If you want to prevent using the improve interface on a rejected edit, make the “Improve” button show an error message rather than the wrong content.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that makes sense, but the reviewing UI offers the opportunity to edit the reviewed text; it doesn't offer the opportunity to convert it to a new answer or comment. I understand we're getting in the weeds a bit here. It just feels like, as a novice reviewer, I'm led down the path of editing the reviewed item, when other options may be more appropriate.